# Delete / remove an attribute from a mixin

Tags: sass, attributes, mixins

The following .scss code:

```
@mixin div-base {
  width: 100px;
  color: red;
}

#data {
  @include div-base;
}
```

will produce:

```
#data {
  width: 100px;
  color: red; }
```

I would like to do something like:

```
#data {
  @include div-base;
  remove or delete: width right here
}
```

to produce:

```
#data {
  color: red;
}
```

Is it even possible to do something along these lines?

Comment: have a base class with the bare minimum and extend it for the `div-base`

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is using [arguments](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixin-arguments) on your mixin:

```
@mixin div-base($width: 100px, $color: red) {
  @if $width != false { width: $width; }
  @if $color != false { color: $color; }
}

#data {
  @include div-base($color: false);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same effect by setting back the width to the default value (set it to `auto`):

```
@mixin div-base {
  width: 100px;
  color: red;
}

#data {
  @include div-base;
  width: auto;
}
```